# How to duplicate a mpegts stream into multiple other UDP streams using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, udp

I'm experimenting with ffmpeg commandline to see to see if I can re-stream a mpegts udp stream in different resolutions.

I succeed in re-streaming an incoming stream into a stream with a different resolution:

`ffmpeg -y -i "udp://234.5.6.7:1234" -vf scale=-1:320 -map 0 -acodec copy -dcodec copy -f mpegts udp://234.5.6.8:1234`

I would like to stream [to multiple output](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs) mpegts streams in various resolutions. I could of course listen from multiple instances to the original broadcast and each stream to a different new endpoint and resolution, but it would be nicer to achieve this with a single ffmpeg call.

Trying to at least output to multiple streams I seem stuck on getting the following to run (even without changing the resolution:)

`ffmpeg -y -i "udp://234.5.6.7:1234" -f tee "[f=mpegts:map=0:acodec=copy:dcodec=copy]udp://234.5.6.8:1234|[f=mpegts:map=0:acodec=copy:dcodec=copy]udp://234.5.6.9:1234"`

This results in the following error:

> Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Could it be that I'm providing the output parameters incorrectly? How would I fix the above line to generate two (or more) output streams?

Comment: Try moving the map out i.e. `-f tee -map 0 "[f=mpegts:aco...."`

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks for your answer! I've tried it and it results in a slightly different issue: `Data stream encoding not supported yet (only streamcopy)`
 I didn't mention that in my question, but that's likely because the broadcast consists of 1 data stream and 1 video stream. So I guess I will somehow have to suggest in the output parameters to streamcopy the data stream (?)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ffmpeg -y -i "udp://234.5.6.7:1234" \
-filter_complex "[0:v]split[a][b];[a]scale=-1:320[v1];[b]scale=-1:480[v2]" \
-map [v1] -map [v2] -map 0:d -dcodec copy \
-f tee "[f=mpegts:select=\'v:0\',d]udp://234.5.6.7:1234|[f=mpegts:select=\'v:1\',d]udp://234.5.6.8:1234"
```

Comment: I feel like we are getting closer. I've removed the **a**-references as there is no audio: `ffmpeg -y -i "udp://234.5.6.7:1234" -filter_complex "[0:v]split[a][b];[a]scale=-1:320[v1];[b]scale=-1:480[v2]" -map [v1] -map [v2] -map 0:d -acodec copy -dcodec copy -f tee "[f=mpegts:select=\'v:0\',d]udp://234.5.6.7:1234|[f=mpegts:select=\'v:1\',d]udp://234.5.6.8:1234"`. This currently leads to a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Comment: I can probably also remove the `-acodec copy`. When I tried that didn't solve the Segmentation fault yet.

Comment: Try now. And if if no, then try outputting to files instead of stream.

Comment: No improvements so far. I've also tried escaping the `':'` like `\'v\:0\'` and `'v\:0'`. And to output to files: `-f tee "[f=mpegts:select='v\:0',d]test_output_a.ts|[f=mpegts:select='v\:1',d]test_output_b.ts"`

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the way the video is referenced after the tee: something like this: `-f tee "[f=mpegts:select=\'v1:v\',d]test_output_a.ts|[f=mpegts:select=\'v2:v\',d]test_output_b.ts"`

Comment: No, keep the original select values. Skip the filters, use `-map 0` and `select=v,d`

Comment: With `ffmpeg -y -i udp://234.5.6.7:1234 -map 0 -acodec copy -dcodec copy -f tee "[f=mpegts:select=d,v]test_out_1.ts|[f=mpegts:select=d,v]test_out_2.ts`. I get an error saying _Encoder (codec none) not found for output stream #0:1_. This might be the real issue. So I've specified it using `-vcodec h264`. This seems to help, but will result in two rather small files (only containing the data streams). Thanks for your continues help! I'll try to test things some more before I come back to you :)

Comment: If there's no input audio, why the acodec? Not needed.